# How to render RDLC reports in a desktop application using .NET 5.0?

Tags: c#, rdlc, reportviewer, .net-5, .net-4.8

My application is a desktop WPF/WinForms application with around a hundred reports heavily customized, some even use code in the report itself. I am willing to lose the report viewer but I need a report renderer for PDF, Excel, and Word.

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/lkosson/reportviewercore ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A desktop app requires Windows (even in .NET 5.0), Windows already have .NET Framework and will support it as long as there are Windows and your desktop app, hence you don't need a service on a server that uses .NET Framework to render your reports. The "simple" solution would be to have a console project that renders reports and uses .NET Framework. All other projects can use .NET standard or .NET 5.0. Console app will of course not have references to your .NET standard or .NET 5.0 projects. I am also having an extra reports project in .NET 5 that will be an implementation for reporting interfaces which I can replace when one day I ditch Framework completely when a full-fledged RDLC renderer appears for new .NET.

.NET 5.0 app will request a report render by calling a console app and getting the rendered report in this way:

.NET 5.0 app:

```
    var process = new Process();
    var info = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "SyriliumRiF.ReportsGenerator.exe",
        //Arguments = "command line arguments to your executable",
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true
    };
    process.StartInfo = info;
    process.Start();

    var base64EncodedData = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    var reportBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedData);
```

Console .NET Framework app:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        byte[] reportBytes = RenderReport(args);
        string str = Convert.ToBase64String(reportBytes);
        Console.Write(str);
    }
}
```

My calls to report viewer in .NET 5 app did not change and I am not generating data sources for the reports in the Framework render app.

Inputs that the render console app receives: report name, report parameters, and files with xml serialized DataTables.
In this way, I was able to detach from .NET Framework and have over 100 reports rendering in just a few days of work.

Comment: This is really interesting, thanks for sharing. How do you pass the xml to the console app ? Do you have a github example for this ?

Comment: "and files with xml serialized DataTables" you serialize DataTables into XML files and you send those file names to the console app in arguments. My argument for a console app is in json format. I don't have it on GitHub. It works great but I've abandoned it because we now have a working .NET Core solution, it's NuGet package ReportViewerCore.NETCore. If you still need my solution for some reason let me know.

Comment: How do you display reportBytes in net 5? Is RenderReport exporting to pdf?

Comment: @andySF in args you define what type of export format you want (PDF, Word, Excel...).

Comment: I see. Thanks. I'm trying to find a viable solution for using Crystal Reports with his viewer and this is a good approach I think. I'm balancing between passing a db id or an encoded dataset somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I am in the same situation, and I found that the best way to solve this
the issue is to isolate the report project into separated service
or exe app,

then use [Inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) to communicate between your app and the reports system.

The best options I found are

- [MagicOnion](https://github.com/Cysharp/MagicOnion)

  - because it built on top of gRPC
    but without the complexity of writing .proto(protocol buffer) contract, and it can directly map the contract data to .Net Types
  - the problem here is the server must be a .Net App, so you should make your main app the server, then make report app/service: the client
- [Pipes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/pipe-operations), it works very well, but read the documentation carefully to be sure that it is satisfied your needs
- [grpc-dotnet-namedpipes](https://github.com/cyanfish/grpc-dotnet-namedpipes/) This is maybe better in your case because it is

  - Windows named pipe transport for gRPC in C#/.NET: so high performance
  - Support .NET Framework 4.6+ (Windows): Client and server
  - Support .NET Core 2.1+ (Windows): Client and server
- For Different Options `old/ may legacy` [Local Machine Interprocess Communication with .NET](https://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/local-machine-interprocess-communication-with-net)